# How to get the observable value inside a .map() function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a function **_populateData** that creates a new list of properties from another list of properties.

There is an observable **getOwnerForProperty** that returns the owner's value.

```
//Get single owner observable
public getOwnerForProperty(prop: any){
    return this._manageOwnerService._getOwnersOfProperty(prop).pipe(map(o => o[0]))
```

How can I call the observable from within the **.map()** function to obtain the observable's value and attach it to the new object as seen below?
In my opinion, it would not be a good idea to subscribe **getOwnerForProperty** function in the **.map()**. Please advise on the best way to approach this following best practices.

```
/**
 * Returns the active properties data.
 * 
 * @param props - The property list.
 * @returns An array of properties 
 */
private _populateData(props: Property[]) {
    return
    const populated = props
        .filter(prop => !prop.isArchived)
        .map((p: Property) => {
            // refactoring here
            this.getOwnerForProperty(p).pipe(
                map((owner: Owner) => {
                    const obj = {
                        propertyName: p.info.name.toUpperCase(),
                        owner: owner.name,
                        createdOn: p.createdOn ? __FormatDateFromStorage(p.createdOn) : ''
                    } 
                    return obj;
                })
               
            )
            

        }
    )
    return populated;
}
}
```

Comment: Does getOwnerForProperty takes an ID and based on that you are making API call to get the data? Does `populateData` returns an array and for each do you need to fetch the data?

Comment: Hi @VimalPatel thank you for responding, the `getOwnerForProperty` function takes a property object. I'm using stores. Yes, the `populateData` returns the new array. For Each property, I want to use the  `getOwnerForProperty` observable and get the value and assign it to the new property object as shown in the **const obj**. My issue is how to properly get the value of the observable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from your question what exactly you are trying to achieve, but here is my solution, so you will hopefully get the idea:

1. filter for the properties you want to "enrich".
2. use `forkJoin` to create an array of observables and wait for all of them to complete.
3. map each property to the observable you want to wait for.
4. map the result of the observable to the initial property and enrich it with the `owner` object.
5. `forkJoin` returns an observable which will basically emit a single array of enriched objects and complete. If you wish to `await` this, you can wrap this in `lastValueFrom` operator, like `await lastValueFrom(forkJoin(...))`

```
function _populateData(props: Property[]) {
  const propertiesToPopulate = props.filter((prop) => !prop.isArchived);

  forkJoin(
    propertiesToPopulate.map((p: Property) => {
      return getOwnerForProperty(p).pipe(
        map((owner) => ({
          ...p,
          owner,
        }))
      );
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: `It's not entirely clear from your question what exactly you are trying to achieve` If an answer starts like that then you should probably clarify things with the OP in a comment first.

Comment: Thank you for the hint Mike, but sometimes a little code to start the discussion is necessary. It's not that I had no clue what the OP's intention was, only minor details were missing, which can be clarified based on the solution I provided. Seems like it wasn't even necessary in this case. Nevertheless I will consider your feedback for future questions.